# How to get the First column value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table without an id. Can I get the inbuilt id column in SQL Server?

It is possible or the question is wrong.

```
      Units     val
 -------------------
 1   mg |ZNS|   NULL
 2   mg |ZNS|   NULL
 3   Mg |ZNS|   NULL
 4   mg |ZNS|   NULL
 5   Mg |ZNS|   NULL
 6   mg |ZNS|   NULL
 7   mgd|ZNS|   NULL
 8   mg |ZNS|   NULL
 9   mgm|ZNS|   NULL
 10  Mg |ZNS|   NULL
```

I have to update a `val` column. How can I do this? The units column having some duplicate values.

Comment: Add a primary key to your table! Any proper table **ought to have** a primary key!

Comment: I don't have rights to edit a table.i have to do up to this table

Comment: The collection you are showing in the example is not technically a table but a bag. As such if you have duplicate rows you can only update all or none of the duplicate rows; you cannot target a subset of the duplicates rows.